# grails/hibernate: how to disable auto-increment on ID column?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

By default, when you create a domain object in grails, it adds the "id" column and sets it to auto-increment in the DB.

I want to supply the id parameter when I create/save an object, not use any kind of generate (its for a small number of static pieces of data which I want the ID to be fixed to the values I give).

There are other benefits I want, e.g. to be able to create an object in memory with the correct ID, without having to read it from the DB then make this object a "contains" type relationship with another object, if that makes sense.

Grails has documenation for the id column, but doesnt say how to disable auto-increment and allow an ID to be passed into the domain object constructor:

http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html

Answer (score 5):

Look at the mappings for the column. According to the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html) you can use `assigned` like this:

```
static mapping = {
    id generator: 'assigned'
}
```

According to the hibernate documentation `assigned` behaves as such:

> lets the application assign an identifier to the object before save()
>   is called. This is the default strategy if no  element is
>   specified.

Comment: Sadly, this does not seem to work.  If I try it, and pass in a id to the constructor, and save it, I get: IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()

Comment: @JohnLittle so why dont you assign it manually before calling save?

Comment: I was hoping to pass in the id in the constructor, e.g. new Status(id:1, name: "active").save().  I see that I could do this: s=new Status(name:"active"); s.id = 1, s.save(), which is more painful as I have a lot of static items to set in the bootstrap.  I looked at overriding the Status constructor, and passing in _id and assigning it, and all the other fields manually, but this is also significant overhead.

Comment: By default the `id` property is not "bindable", i.e. it's ignored with using the map constructor, and when setting properties in bulk (e.g. `foo.properties = params`). Either set it explicitly after the constructor call, or make the `id` property bindable with the [bindable constraint](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/bindable.html). Note that making the property bindable this is somewhat unsafe; `id` and `version` are auto-excluded by Grails (in addition to the default `class` and `metaClass` exclusions that Groovy adds) because only Hibernate should set or update those values.